# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js)

Tags: html, css, sass

In the folder `app`, I created a folder `styles > custom > loader.scss`. Then, in the `styles.scss` file, I add this import:

```
@import "styles/custom/loader.scss";
```

The problem is that I have an error message:

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import "styles/custom/loader.scss";
```

I don't know how can I solve this problem, please.

Files structure:

[image]

I don't know how can I solve this problem please?

Comment: Where `styles.scss` is located?

Comment: @yousoumar, on the same level as `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an incorrect path based on how your files are structured. Try doing so instead:

```scss
@import "./app/styles/custom/loader.scss";
```